# How to bounty a question on meta?

Tags: support, bounties

I was expecting, when clicking on the `Badges` option, for the results to be the same whether from meta or main, though I appreciate what is displayed at the very top of the page, between reputation and total posts awaiting review (when shown) differs - but then reputation differs between the main and meta anyway.

Obviously that is not the case but this drew my attention to the first entry on the meta version: `Altruist`, a badge for *First bounty you manually award on another person's question*.

There are [a number of Qs of mine](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A4995+is%3Aq+answers%3A0) on meta I would appreciate As to and many from other users too.

How might I offer a bounty on these as meta does not seem to have a `start a bounty` button where it may be found on main (ie near the Q's `add a comment`)?

---

Related: [What are the odds of SE implementing an old feature request and what can be done to improve those odds?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290410/what-are-the-odds-of-se-implementing-an-old-feature-request-and-what-can-be-done)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [cannot bounty a question on stack Metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78264), only [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75866). There have been [feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231215/) to add bounties to stack Metas, but perhaps because scoring of Meta questions and answers does not affect reputation, and because the relationship between promotion and participation would be less direct as a consequence, no action has been taken.

There is always shog9's post offering **[5 crazy tricks that'll get you mega meta attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263059)**.